# Update Multiple checkbox if it checked or not

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a problem in updating multiple checkboxes

I have the following ,

if the price is checked then I will calculate its total price if not then the total price is 0

so I have this in the view

```
    <?php echo form_open("/lab-forms/save/$id_form") ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" <?php if($price->is_checked==1) { echo 'checked="checked"';}?> value=<?php echo $price->id; ?>></td>
    <td><?php echo $price->price; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $price->qt; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $price->total_price; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I want to get the checked and the unchecked ones cause the default on the database is checked

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ($price->is_checked == 1 ? "checked='checked'" : "")
```

This is exactly like

```
if($price->is_checked == 1) {

    echo "checked='checked'";
    }
    else {
    ....you know....
    }
```

Just easier yo use for situations like these one